# LSTM with high sequence length (Tensorflow and Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

i have currently a big problem with Tensorflow and LSTMs and cant find a solution:

I wanna use a LSTM with a big sequence_length = 100.
for the model i have this configuration:

```
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(1, x.shape[1])))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

my input x (with 4 independent input variables) is a an array with a specific length with normalized values...
the columns are each independent input variables:
here the first 3 lines

```
array([[-0.82425835, -0.58544026,  1.51368749, -1.00692614],
       [-0.82227587, -0.58777757,  1.51125719, -1.00782088],
       [-0.82254579, -0.57388769,  1.50873596, -1.00916302],
...
       ]])
```

the output y, or let's say the variable which shall be predicted is another independent variable.
right now i have it in this specific shape/data type:

```
array([[-0.43949472],
       [-0.43949472],
       [-0.43949472],
    ...]])
```

Till now i used Keras preprocessing funtion:

```
dataset = keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(x, y, sequence_length=1, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=128)
```

For sequence_length=1 everything is running with the fit command:

```
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=1000, callbacks=sel_callback)
```

Now i want to use the LSTM, like I think it should used, with a longer sequence length of 100.
if i just change the `sequence_length` option in the Keras preprocessing function everything starts, and Tensorflow tells me that i have a high accuracy of e.g. 0.03 but the output at the end looks totally wrong!
Do I have to preprocess the data differently?! (for sequence length=1 it works fine...)

---

In addition, if i want to add another LSTM, e.g.:

```
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(1, x.shape[1])))
model.add(LSTM(10,  return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

then i get an error and the model doesnt work at all... With `sequence_length=1` adding the 2nd LSTM is working?

the error looks like that:

```
File "...\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:    Operation expected a list with 1 elements but got a list with 2 elements.
         [[{{node gradients/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor_grad/TensorListStack}}]]
         [[PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_13514]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function -> train_function
```

So my questions:

- Do i have to prepare my data differently with a high sequence length? or do i have a different problem which i havent located?
- Why cant i add a second layer when i change my sequence_length>1 ??

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a problem with preparing data with a higher sequence length (although 100 doesn't seem that high). You could change in your model `model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(None, x.shape[1])))`, so you don't have to change the input_shape for different sequence length values.
When you say:

> Tensorflow tells me that i have a high accuracy of e.g. 0.03

do you mean in terms of mean square error (for example), not in terms of accuracy ? This is a regression problem.
I replicated your problem with synthetic data and adding a second LSTM was not a problem. However, a more complex model corresponds to more complex data in terms of dependencies. In your dataset, as I understand it, all variables are independent. This could be a problem as you are trying to make predictions...